# How know if an iframe content is empty or not?

Tags: php, iframe, web-scraping

I need know if this page returns something, because this page have a login in ASP and my server is a PHP.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "empty". A loaded page with no content? No loaded page?

Comment: dont use iframes they're icrap

Answer (score 1):

http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/